# Different Width's using FramerJs

Tags: framerjs

I am trying to build tags in framerjs , where they can have auto width depending upon their text.

It is possible to have auto width for a layer or max-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = new Layer(backgroundColor: "red")
text.style.width = "auto"
text.style.fontSize = "2em"
text.html = "abcd"
```

"auto" property cannot be used in initializer(ex, `new Layer(width: "auto")`), but can be passed via `style` property.